# Prism / Unity update resolved/injected references with new concrete class

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism

I'm trying to change the concrete type at run-time for a type registered during startup. I'm able to update the container & service locator. But already existing view models still have reference to the original service bootstrapped.

Bootstrap Code:

```
container.RegisterInstance<IMyService>(new MyServiceA(), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

ViewModelCode:

```
public ViewModel(IMyService service)
{
    _service = service;
}
```

Service Changing Code:

```
container.RegisterInstance<IMyService>(new MyServiceB(), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

serviceLocator.Resolve returns MyServiceB. MyServiceA no longer exists in the container. But existing view models still have reference to MyServiceA.

Is there any way to have updates to the container update existing/resolved references?

**UPDATE:**
Maybe this unit test can help understand the behavior I'm fighting.

```
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

    namespace UnitTestProject1
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class UnitTest1
        {      
            [TestMethod]
            public void TestUnity()
            {
                // register ServiceA and ViewModel
                var container = new UnityContainer();
                container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyServiceA>();
                container.RegisterType<MyViewModel>();

                // resolve viewmodel
                var viewModel = container.Resolve<MyViewModel>();

                // replace ServiceA with ServiceB
                container.RegisterInstance<IMyService>(new MyServiceB());

                // Assert success, IMyService is MyServiceB
                Assert.AreEqual(container.Resolve<IMyService>().GetType(), typeof(MyServiceB));
                // Assert fails viewmodel still using MyServiceA
                Assert.AreEqual(viewModel.RegisteredService.GetType(), typeof(MyServiceB));
            }
        }    

        public interface IMyService
        {        
        }

        public class MyServiceA : IMyService
        {
        }

        public class MyServiceB : IMyService
        {
        }

        public class MyViewModel
        {
            public IMyService RegisteredService { get; }

            public MyViewModel(IMyService myService)
            {
                RegisteredService = myService;
            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll implement [Proxy-class](http://www.oodesign.com/proxy-pattern.html) for IMyService which'll retrieve the actual implementation from [ServiceLocator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648968.aspx) per each call the problem will be solved:

```
public class MyServiceProxy : IMyService
{
    public int DoWork(string someParameter)
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Resolve<IMyService>().DoWork(someParameter);
    }
}
```

Now you can inject MyServiceProxy to your class constructor. The other way is to add an explicit call of ServiceLocator to each IMyService usage. But you should remember that ServiceLocator can make your code more complicated to understand because it hides class dependences.

**UPDATE**

Situation with bindings to the retrieved data reminds the reaction to the event. When event "Data source changed" raises in your system the subscribers (ViewModels) sholud handle this event. It's work for [EventAggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) class which has implementation [in Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx).

Then the solution based on 2 parts:

1. [Subscribe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921131.aspx) your ViewModels which uses IMyService to MyServiceChangedEvent (first you should implement it). In the handlers you can change implementation via ServiceLocator or **via event parameters**, raise PropertyChanged for update databinding and do another actions for your cases.

   ```
   public class MyServiceChangedEvent : CompositeWpfEvent<IMyService>
   {
   }
   ```
2. [Publish new MyServiceChangedEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921148.aspx) on IMyService changed. You can create new property inside your event to pass new implementation to your subscribers instead of using ServiceLocator.

   ```
   var newMyService = new MyServiceB();
   container.RegisterInstance<IMyService>(newMyService, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
   eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyServiceChangedEvent>().Publish(newMyService);
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. It fills the need but I'm hoping I can come up with some canned unity functionality i'm missing here. Maybe other containers update references directly. I'll let you know what I find out.

Comment: I like this approach a lot. Not only does it manage to get the service references updated. There is a place for handling switching of the service. Which is probably good to have because there may be problems just switching out the service without any notification.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use named instances?

```
_container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>("ServiceA", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
_container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyOtherService>("ServiceB", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

_container.Resolve<IMyService>("ServiceA");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brian. If a 'locator' was exposing a type as a property and I reference that property in a view model, then change the property value in the locator does the view model object reference/value get updated? Maybe I'm confusing locator behavior with container behavior. Maybe trying to re-instance the registered type with a new concrete instance is a bad idea. I'm going to have a dozen controls/view models that need to support switching between ServiceA and ServiceB at runtime. I was hoping updating the 'source' (in the container) of the value would update everyone's value.

Comment: I updated the question above with a little unit test. Maybe that'll help iron things out. Or maybe I've gone off the reservation, either way thanks!

Comment: Something just doesn't seem right with the functionality of this "service" and how its implementation completely changes during runtime.  Seems like an architecture discussion is needed.  Based on what you have now, I would probably suggest dropping the use of a container and just use a static property to maintain the service. With a static property, when you update the ref, everything uses it automatically gets it too.

Comment: ISportClock is a service that runs a clock for sports games. Different sports have different implementations. Football counts down from 15 minutes, Basketball 12, Soccer counts up. A single configurable service could work but rules get complicated quickly especially integrating with other services like IGameTimeout. Re-registering the concrete type/implementation when switching between sports was the idea. Thanks again for everything.